# Running substrate-node-template throws macOS memory error

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I am using substrate-node-template. I don't have any issue building the substrate-node-template in release mode, and when I try to run it the first time it works fine, but if I stop and try to run it again I get the below error. I am facing the same error even after using the `purge-chain` command.

macOS:

```
Apple M1 pro
Ventura 13.2.1
```

Rust tools :

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.67.1 (d5a82bbd2 2023-02-07)
```

```
./target/release/node-template --dev
```

```
2023-03-10 23:31:52 NODE TEMPLATE
2023-03-10 23:31:52 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-3cd46c7e0cb    
2023-03-10 23:31:52 ❤️  by XXX, 2017-2023    
2023-03-10 23:31:52  Chain specification: Development    
2023-03-10 23:31:52   Node name: happy-smash-3827    
2023-03-10 23:31:52  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-03-10 23:31:52  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/substrate0dMzee/chains/dev/db/full    
2023-03-10 23:31:52 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)    
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("can't convert a memory import into an export: failed to insert a new memory section: Duplicated sections (5)")))
2023-03-10 23:31:52 Cannot create a runtime error=Other("can't convert a memory import into an export: failed to insert a new memory section: Duplicated sections (5)")
```

Error

```
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("can't convert a memory import into an export: failed to insert a new memory section: Duplicated sections (5)")))
2023-03-10 23:31:52 Cannot create a runtime error=Other("can't convert a memory import into an export: failed to insert a new memory section: Duplicated sections (5)")
```

Comment: Hi Nagaraj! Sorry to hear about the issue you're getting. Does your node produce blocks after the first time you launch it? It may be that your machine doesn't have any memory left to run the node.

Comment: Hi @SachaLansky, `node-template` works well, when I run for first time and it creates blocks too but Incase if I stop the node and try to start again or after using the `purge-chain` command, it throws the above error.

Comment: @SachaLansky is their any solution to fix this issue.

Comment: I found out that in runtime folder  `build.rs` line number 7 which use wasm builder import the memory but not clearing previous build `.import_memory()`

Comment: Please share a link to your node and maybe I can see what the problem is. With this information, the issue you're reporting doesn't make sense.

Comment: please find the link for repo : https://github.com/nagarajmanjunath/substrate_pallet_contract first time it works well but stop and run again throw above error. I am using Mac M1 pro, I need to comment `import_memory()`  to run it properly.